how do you install AG-Grid with NextJS 14 and TypeScript?
I'm having trouble using AG-Grid with NextJS 14.  I'm getting the following error message below.  Any assistance is much appreciated:
ERROR message
"Package path ./dist/styles/ag-grid.css is not exported from package"
This is the code I used to install the package:
npm install --save ag-grid-community ag-grid-react

And this is the code I used to import:
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react'; import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css'; import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';
I was expecting the library to work.

I figured it out.  The path has changed.  Needed to remove "dist".  Was able ot figure it out by going into the package.json file for ag-grid located in node_modules and found under exports that the "dist" was missing.
The new paths are:
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';

